Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS tearing and not working properly with AMD RX 6600 XT
I'm having this issue when trying to install Pop!_OS on my system. I have tried Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS before on another computer with an Nvidia GPU, but in my current one with an AMD RX 6600 XT it just won't work well. When I'm on the live session, all the windows and the display in general starts tearing, when I try to open some stuff like the app launcher it doesn't show in the middle of the screen but in the upper left corner, etc.
Have someone tried to use this distro with an RX 6600 XT? Is it that it won't work with this specific GPU or maybe I need to set up something in order to be able to use Pop!_OS? Also, I want to clarify that after I tried to open Firefox on the live session, the problem got solved and I was able to install the distro, but after I finished the installation and after I logged in, the screen went black and I was only able to see the mouse's cursor.
I would really appreciate if someone know about this problem and can maybe help me with it. :)

Nevermind. I found what the actual problem is. Pop!_OS by default activates the HiDPI option that allows you to avoid problems when using an HiDPI laptop and then you connect an LoDPI monitor, but in my case with my LoDPI monitor it seems to give serious problems, so the solution is just turning off HiDPI.
If you have this same problem after Logging in and you don't see the Desktop, then you just need to press Ctrl + Alt + F5, then you log in with your username and password, and then use this command:
gsettings set com.system76.hidpi enable false.
Then you just reboot and after that you should be able to use the system as I am now. :)
